# swap images w/ jquery based on their existence on the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been trying to figure out this semi-specific problem for the past couple days, and I could really use another pair of eyes on it.

My goal is to have an image on the page. It starts out as a static png, and when it's clicked, it swaps out with a .gif and plays an animation. When it's click on again, it swaps again and plays a second .gif animation. It does the same thing a third time. When the 3rd .gif is clicked on, it plays the 1st gif animation again, and the process starts all over again.

My issue is that multiple images are loaded on the page, and some have 3 total gif animations, some have 2, and some have one.

So what I'm trying to do is check if the .gifs exist before I load the next one.

Here's an excerpt with some of my notation...

```
$('#postContainer img').click(function () {            
    imgSrc = $(this).attr('src');    
    if(imgSrc.indexOf('_B.png') != -1){
        imgSrcToUse = imgSrc.replace('_B.png', '_pt1.gif');
        $(this).attr('src', imgSrcToUse);
        return false;
    }
```

That code above runs when the image is clicked. It finds the image src, and replace the static png with the first animated gif. all the images have an animated gif, so this isn't a problem.

```
if (imgSrc.indexOf('_pt1.gif') != -1) {
    var POS2 = imgSrc.replace('_pt1.gif', '_pt2.gif');
    $.ajax({
        url: POS2,
        type: 'HEAD',
        error: function() {
            alert('error');
            imgSrcToUse = imgSrc.replace('_pt1.gif', '_pt1.gif');
        },
        success: function() {
            alert('success');
            imgSrcToUse = imgSrc.replace('_pt1.gif', '_pt2.gif');
        }
    });        

    $(this).attr('src', imgSrcToUse);
    return false;
}
```

After `_pt1` is loaded, then this function runs the next time you click. it is supposed to check if a `_pt2` exists, and if it does, then swap out the pt1 with pt2. HOWEVER, it only seems to be working on the second click. if i click it once, it loads `_pt1` again, and then the second time through it will load `_pt2` properly. this is where my major problem lies...

i apologize if this is convoluted but i'm really stumped here. i'll try to do my best to clear things up if you guys are way too confused.

Comment: When the page loads, do you know how many different gifs each `<img>` can have?

Comment: no, not initially. so i was going to check if the following gif exists each time an image is clicked. (click pt1-> check if pt2 exists->load pt2 else load pt1, etc)

Comment: It probably makes more sense to check before the click, if you check if an image exists every time you click, you're slowing down the image changing by a lot

Comment: i've preloaded all the images in a hidden container, so the change is pretty quick. for some reason though the image takes two clicks to change instead of one.

Comment: Hm, if you preload all the images somewhere, that makes it a bit easier. You can use selectors to see if the image exists within the hidden container, something like `if ($('.hidden img[src="' + url + '"]).length > 0)` then use the next image else go back the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your issue:

```
   $.ajax({
        url:POS2,
        type:'HEAD',
        error: function()
        {
            alert('error');
            imgSrcToUse = imgSrc.replace('_pt1.gif','_pt1.gif');
        },
        success: function()
        {
            alert('success');
            imgSrcToUse = imgSrc.replace('_pt1.gif','_pt2.gif');
        }
    });     

    $(this).attr('src',imgSrcToUse);
```

That last line of code is trying to use your variable `imgSrcToUse`, which doesn't contain the result of your AJAX query yet. `AJAX` is asynchronous, so your `$.ajax` call returns and moves onto the next line before the success (or error) callbacks are called. You can resolve this by moving the code using the data from the callbacks into the callbacks:

```
var $that = $(this);
$.ajax({
    url: POS2,
    type: 'HEAD',
    error: function () {
        alert('error');
        var imgSrcToUse = imgSrc.replace('_pt1.gif', '_pt1.gif');

        $that.attr('src', imgSrcToUse);
    },
    success: function () {
        alert('success');
        var imgSrcToUse = imgSrc.replace('_pt1.gif', '_pt2.gif');

        $that.attr('src', imgSrcToUse);
    }
});
```

You were seeing sucess on the second call because you were assigning the next image name to a global variable. You should use `var` to avoid this.